# How to watch transcoded video from transcode?

Tags: video-editor, video-conversion, transcode

I used command transcode -J stabilize --mplayer_probe -i "Video.MOV" and after that I've got an output file with .trf. What to do now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

.TRF is a file extension used for multiple different purposes. In this case, it's a temporary file generated by [Transcode](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man1/transcode.1.html), along with other temporary files .PID, .MLT, and .LOG. http://www.bernaerts-nicolas.fr/linux/74-ubuntu/350-ubuntu-xenial-rotate-stabilize-video-melt-vidstab shows it should have been deleted in the cleanup of those temporary files.